# WordPress database error Illegal mix of collations utf8mb3_general_ci,IMPLICIT and utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,COERCIBLE

Tags: database, point, collation

WordPress database error Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb3_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like' for query
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS shop_posts.ID
FROM shop_posts
WHERE 1=1 AND (((shop_posts.post_title LIKE '%156-608試験の準備方法｜100％合格率の156-608 資格認証攻略試験｜最新のCheck Point Certified Security Expert R81.20 - Practice 日本語試験情報  最新【 156-608 】問題集ファイルは➡ [www.goshiken.com](http://www.goshiken.com) ️⬅️にて検索156-608過去問%') OR (shop_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%156-608試験の準備方法｜100％合格率の156-608 資格認証攻略試験｜最新のCheck Point Certified Security Expert R81.20 - Practice 日本語試験情報  最新【 156-608 】問題集ファイルは➡ [www.goshiken.com](http://www.goshiken.com) ️⬅️にて検索156-608過去問%') OR (shop_posts.post_content LIKE '%156-608試験の準備方法｜100％合格率の156-608 資格認証攻略試験｜最新のCheck Point Certified Security Expert R81.20 - Practice 日本語試験情報  最新【 156-608 】問題集ファイルは➡ [www.goshiken.com](http://www.goshiken.com) ️⬅️にて検索156-608過去問%'))) AND (shop_posts.post_password = '') AND ((shop_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (shop_posts.post_status = 'publish')))

ORDER BY (CASE WHEN shop_posts.post_title LIKE '%156-608試験の準備方法｜100％合格率の156-608 資格認証攻略試験｜最新のCheck Point Certified Security Expert R81.20 - Practice 日本語試験情報  最新【 156-608 】問題集ファイルは➡ [www.goshiken.com](http://www.goshiken.com) ️⬅️にて検索156-608過去問%' THEN 2 ELSE 6 END), shop_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts

I do not know what to do and what should I do?